# How to track server side redirect in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have article pages. Few of them redirected to some of external link. This is happening on server side. When user click on internal article link then on controller side its redirect to external article.

I saw few blocks which discuss about outbound link click tracking, but in our case redirect doesn't happens on any click event. So how we can track this interaction in google analytics ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to track how many times a user is clicking/opening an article, you can do this very easily. Assuming you use some sort of tag manager (e.g. Google Tag Manager) you would need to do the following:

- Create a trigger which listens for clicks on article link elements (could be an HTML link element: `<a>`, `<div>`, `<p>`, etc.)
- Create a variable which captures some information about the element which got clicked (e.g. the click URL, data-attributes, etc.)
- Create a google analytics tag, and set it's tag type to "event". You'll need to populate the following fields:

  - Google Tracking ID (google analytics property tracking id)
  - Event Category (e.g. click)
  - Event Action (e.g. article)
  - Event Label (e.g. `{variable you created earlier}`)
- Preview your tag manager container and ensure that tracking is behaving as expected
- Publish the container

Answer (score 0):

One way to see which page views are the result of internal redirects would be to add a query parameter in the redirect and then set a  hit-based custom dimension based on that parameter.

Or better, send a cookie header in your redirect with a first party cookie with a very short lifetime, and base your custom dimension on that (so people can share the url without propagation your redirect parameter along).

As a caveat, both solutions would require that you change the redirect code.